# Evaluating the limit of a multi-variable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to(0, 0)}\frac{(\sin y)(2^x - 1)}{xy}$$

I have no idea how to even approach this. I can't find a way to simplify this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of derivative at the origin for the $2^x$ part and the fact that $\sin y\cdot y^{-1}\to 1$ as $y\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do the question.